# how to pivot a Dataframe groupby results

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

I have following dataframe:

```
test=pd.DataFrame({'MKV':[50,1000,80,20],
                  'Rating':['A','Z','A','A'],
                  'Sec':['I','I','I','F']})

test.groupby(['Rating','Sec'])['MKV'].apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())
gives results:
0   0.38
1   1.00
2   0.62
3   1.00
```

How can I pivot this groupby results, to put results from each group into a separate column?
[image]

Comment: `x/x.sum()` will return a series, not a scalar, so can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to do a `groupby`.  You can pivot by using [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), and then normalize the columns:

```
# Perform the pivot.
test = test.set_index(['Rating','Sec'], append=True).unstack(['Rating','Sec'])

# Normalize the columns.
test = test/test.sum()

# Rename columns as appropriate.
test.columns = [','.join(c[1:]) for c in test.columns]
```

The resulting output:

```
        A,I  Z,I  A,F
0  0.384615  NaN  NaN
1       NaN  1.0  NaN
2  0.615385  NaN  NaN
3       NaN  NaN  1.0
```